# Adding code to send referrer on login page

Tags: code

I have a code i need to add to the wordpress/woocommerce login page

```php
function fix_lack_of_referrer_login() {
    ?>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
    <?php
}

add_action( 'login_head', 'fix_lack_of_referrer_login', 100 );
```

What is the best way to put this on the login page?

Comment: Is this a multisite? Your options are putting it in a simple plugin, or your theme if it's custom / you've customised it with a child theme, or a simple mu-plugin. If this is a multisite I think it has to be a mu-plugin.

Comment: It is not a multi-site. Our theme does have a child theme with functions.php section.